# Run R scripte from Python with arg input

Tags: python, r, subprocess

```
import subprocess

Iterations = 10
command = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/Rscript.exe'
path2script = 'C:/Users/a0266997/Documents/PossionDistribution.R'
args = [str(Iterations)]
cmd = [command, path2script] + args
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

The code works perfectly fine when there is no "+ args" at cmd line

However, after added "+ args", the R script doesn't output a csv file which it does before. Any tips of how to pass the args from Python to R? How the R code should look like ( Iterations =  as.numeric(cmd[2]) is not right) ?  I'd appreciate

Comment: Does it work if you run `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/Rscript.exe C:/Users/a0266997/Documents/PossionDistribution.R 10` directly in `cmd.exe`? Your Python looks fine.

Comment: Thanks, what is code should be to run in cmd?   If I type in: 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/Rscript.exe', 'C:/Users/a0266997/Documents/Casualty/CasualtyEventPossionDistribution.R', '200', I got error: ''C' is not recognized as internal or external command....

Comment: Try copying exactly what is in my comment, but run it in PowerShell, rather than cmd.

Comment: I got this error: C:/Program : The term 'C:/Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,

Comment: Sorry! Try this in `CMD.exe`: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\a0266997\Documents\PossionDistribution.R" 10`

Comment: The quote marks are needed, because there is a space in "Program Files", and we need to change all the forward slashes to back slashes, because Windows likes to be different.

Comment: I got error as : At line:1 char:46
+ "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\a0266997\Documents\Possio ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '"C:\Users\a0266997\Documents\PossionDistribution.R"' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:98
+ ... istribution.R" 10
+                    ~~
Unexpected token '10' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Alright! So that's the real problem. That's the reason why it doesn't work when you add the `+ args`  Does it work if you run the same thing without the `10` at the end?

Comment: after taking off "10" I got error: At line:1 char:46
+ "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\a0266997\Documents\Possio ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '"C:\Users\a0266997\Documents\PossionDistribution.R"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Could you put both files online so I can check what's happening? You could post them here: https://gist.github.com

Comment: They are at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a28b2f3728e87f673525613bd10978cb now